# Android localize xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, localization, plist

I have several Xml in different languages, however when I get the XmlResourceParser programatically I'm always getting the default language.

This is how I'm getting the Xml programatically:

```
XmlResourceParser xpp = TCXApplication.getContext().getResources().getXml(R.xml.some_name);
```

My Xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>type</key>
            <string>some</string>
            <key>other_some</key>
            <array>
                <string>...</string>
                <string>...</string>
                <string>...</string>
            </array>
            <key>other_other_some</key>
            <array>
                <string>...</string>
                <string>...</string>
                <string>...</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

I have different versions of this file in different folders for every language (xml, xml-es, xml-fr, xml-it) but I'm always getting the default version even when I change my device language to some of the other languages...
Am I doing something wrong? Is there no way localize plist?

Thanks for the help. Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to localize my xml files, what I did was to move my files to the raw folder, so I ended up with an (raw, raw-es, raw-it, raw-fr)

And to parse the information from them I use:

```
private List<PlistItem> parse() {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = MyApplication.getContext().getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.raw.some);
            XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
            xmlPullParser.setInput(inputStream, null);

            String key = null;
            PlistItem item = null;
            int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();
            while (!(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG
                    && xmlPullParser.getName() != null
                    && xmlPullParser.getName().equals("plist"))) {

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                    list = new ArrayList<>();
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().contentEquals(PLIST_ELEMENT_DICT)) {
                    item = new PlistItem();
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().contentEquals(PLIST_ELEMENT_DICT)) {
                    list.add(item);
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().contentEquals(PLIST_ELEMENT_KEY)) {
                    xmlPullParser.next();
                    key = xmlPullParser.getText();
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xmlPullParser.getName().contentEquals(PLIST_ELEMENT_STRING)) {
                    xmlPullParser.next();

                    if (key != null && item != null) {
                        if (key.contentEquals(PLIST_VALUE_TYPE)) {
                            item.type = xmlPullParser.getText();
                        }
                        if (key.contentEquals(PLIST_VALUE_SOME)) {
                            item.some.add(xmlPullParser.getText());
                        }
                        if (key.contentEquals(PLIST_VALUE_OTHER_SOME)) {
                            item.otherSome.add(xmlPullParser.getText());
                        }
                    }
                }

                eventType = xmlPullParser.next();
            }

            inputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

I hope this can be useful for someone in the future.
Regards
Jose